# why does my trigger function cause a null error?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

PostgreSQL.
My trigger func:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_purchase() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $psql$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM currents c
        WHERE c.name = new.name
    )
    THEN
        INSERT INTO currents (name, qty)
        VALUES (new.name, new.qty);
    ELSE
        UPDATE currents
        SET
            qty = qty + new.qty
        WHERE
            name = new.name;
    END IF;
    return new;
END;
$psql$ language plpgsql;
```

Then my trigger:

```
create trigger new_purchase_trigger 
after insert on purchases 
for each statement 
execute procedure new_purchase();
```

my two tables with which i am manipulating:
Purchases

```
CREATE TABLE purchases (
  name VARCHAR,
  date TIMESTAMP,
  qty INTEGER,
  price NUMERIC,
  about VARCHAR
)
```

Currents

```
CREATE TABLE currents (
  name VARCHAR,
  qty INTEGER
)
```

My INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO purchases (name, date, qty, price, about)
VALUES ('cheese', '2022-07-31', 1000, 11500, 'holland');
```

And finally the error when i am adding data to purchases via INSERT INTO - VALUES:

> ERROR: NULL value in column "name" of relation "currents" violates the NOT NULL constraint
> DETAIL: Error string contains (null, null).
> CONTEXT: SQL statement: "INSERT INTO currents (name, qty)
> VALUES(new.name, new.qty)"
> PL/pgSQL new_purchase() function, line 9, statement SQL statement
> SQL state: 23502

Comment: edited it with insert code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a **ROW** level trigger for what you are trying to achieve. In a statement level trigger (`for each statement`) the record `new` is not populated:

```
create trigger new_purchase_trigger 
after insert on purchases 
for each row
execute procedure new_purchase();
```

Note that you can simplify your trigger function if you declare `currents.name` as the primary key:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_purchase() 
RETURNS TRIGGER 
AS $psql$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO currents (name, qty)
  VALUES (new.name, new.qty)
  on conflict (name) do update
    set qty = currents.qty + excluded.qty;
  return new;
END;
$psql$ 
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: and how i check here if there is already row with such name in my second table? Where is if else or it's alternative in ur code. I dont really understand it)

Comment: The `insert on conflict()` together the with the primary (=unique) key will take care of that (and much more efficiently and safe than your solution)

Comment: thxs a lot really gratefull, a nice experience for me))